# Nice gui habit tracker for windows 10 or web based at affordable subscription rates?

Tags: web-apps, windows-10, time-management, productivity

I tried lunatask, ticktick and wasn't very satisfied with them(specially their GUI). I can pay about 5USD per month(Sorry I am poor).
Anything you would recommend to me?

For example this is the kind of workflow I am looking into:

Goals:

- Learn Linux
- Learn Kubernetes
- Learn Docker
- Learn Hugo for blogging
- Write 1 blog post
- 6 hrs of intensive study during fridays and saturdays
- 3 hrs of study everyday besides job
- Deliberate practice(just remember this time to time basis)

And so on.

My metrics that I want are:

- Why am I doing this?
- Reminder on specific day about specific issue.
- Statistics like heatmap or some form of charts.
- Percentage of completion of goal
- How long the goal will last? Duration of goal?

Comment: obsidian can do this but IDK hwo to do it :(

Answer (score 0):

All of your requirements sound like typical project management app features. You could take a look at e.g. free version of [Jira](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira), which lets you:

- add various tasks to be done within certain timeframes
- track required time and time left
- rate with points how much of the task has been done
- check statistics of all tasks